# Option to get the rust project dir in shell script?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am writing some shell scripts in a rust project like this to auto-generate the schema and model files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -u
set -e
set -x

diesel_ext --derive Insertable,Queryable,Debug,Serialize,Deserialize,Default \
--add-table-name \
--import-types "rocket::serde::Serialize" \
--import-types "serde::Deserialize" \
--import-types "crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::*" \
--schema-file src/model/diesel/dolphin/dolphin_schema.rs --model > src/model/diesel/dolphin/dolphin_models.rs
```

This script work fine but I could not easily move the shell script when refactoring the project code. Sometimes I need to move the shell script to another folder and make the code file structure more clear and understandable.

Without knowing the project dir, I could not move the shell script because when I move it, I have to change the folder relative path in the shell script.

Is it possible to get a project dir to make this work more smoothly? Just like the Gradle `project.dir`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cargo locate-project` will output a JSON description of the path to the project's `Cargo.toml` file, which you can pipe through `jq` and process with `dirname` to find the directory.

You could then give this to e.g. `cd` to switch directories.

```
cd "$(dirname "$(cargo locate-project | jq -r .root)")"
```

(There may be error conditions that need to be handled.)

Comment: neat! I wondered how but never knew `cargo` exported such a useful sub command.

Comment: Just a note, but I searched through the help doc and found that you can pass in a `--message-format plain` argument to avoid having to parse through the json output with `jq`.